# Too many redirections were attempted using WebRequest

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webrequest

When trying to grab the html of a webpage, very occasionally I get the exception "Too many redirections were attempted".

An example of such a website is http://www.magicshineuk.co.uk/

Normally I would set the timeout to be something like 6 seconds... but even with 30 seconds, and Max Redirections Allowed to something crazy like 200, it will still throw either the "Too many redirections" exception, or, a Timeout will occur.

How can I get around this problem?

My code is below...

```
    try
{

   System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.magicshineuk.co.uk/");

   var hwr = ((HttpWebRequest)request);

   hwr.UserAgent ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0";
   hwr.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
   hwr.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

   hwr.ContentType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"; ;
   hwr.KeepAlive = true;
   hwr.Timeout = 30000;   // 30 seconds...  normally set to 6000
   hwr.Method = "GET";
   hwr.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
   hwr.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

   // Setting this Makes no difference... normally I would like to keep to a sensible maximum but I will leave as the default of 50 if needs be... 
   // Either way, the Too Many Redirections exception occurs
   hwr.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 200;   

   using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.GetResponse())
   {

       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusCode));
       Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);
       Console.WriteLine("Last modified: {0}", response.LastModified);
       Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}", response.Server);
       Console.WriteLine("Supports Headers: {0}", response.SupportsHeaders);
       Console.WriteLine("Headers: ");

       // do something... e.g:
       int keyCount = response.Headers.Keys.Count;
       int i = 0;
       Dictionary<string, string> hc = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       foreach (var hname in response.Headers)
       {
          var hv = response.Headers[i].ToString();
          hc.Add(hname.ToString(), hv);
          i++;
       }
       foreach (var di in hc)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", di.Key, di.Value);
       }

   }


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: ");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, for which I needed to comment out   `// hwr.Host = Utils.GetSimpleUrl(url);`   and it worked fine. If you are polling frequently, then the target site, or something in between (proxy, firewall etc), may be recognizing your polling as a denial of service and  timing you out for a set duration. Alternatively, if you are behind a corporate firewall you may be receiving similar from an internal network appliance.

How often are you running this scraper?

Edited to add:

- I tried this using .net 4.52, Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2015
- The target site could also be unreliable (up and down)
- There may be intermittent network problems between you and the target site
- They may possibly expose an API which would be a more reliable integration

Comment: My mistake. The line you removed was the culprit!  My function "GetSimpleUrl(url)" was returning "magicshineuk.co.uk", hence the redirection because the Host is set before the request is made.  The code actually runs fine now.

Comment: For the record, I removed the line  hwr.Host = Utils.GetSimpleUrl(url); to avoid confusion .The code is now fine for others to use.. .

Comment: FTW! Glad it's now sorted.